# What does the word "live"mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't understand the exact meaning of the word "live" here. Does it refer to live perfomances, that means that Queen didn't use phonogram or it means "full of life, energy or activity"? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/live

Queen is significant in the sense that they are one of the major bands that manage to bring a theatrical element to rock music in mainstream consciousness. Despite that, however, they never felt too cheesy or unnecessarily flashy. They were also consistent live and rarely ever messed up any of their performances musically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It refers to live performances in context.**

Clarification: *They didn't mess up, they always gave it their best, and never were displeasing to the crowd.* - Consistent live.
The example sentence has a bigger context (Queen, concerts), and a smaller one, about musical performances and playing live. (Heavily implying non-playback and such, as well.)

Reading the sentence out loud can help make more sense, by reading the word live can lose a bit of emphasis on things.